# Is narcist an accepted spelling of narcissist?

Tags: orthography

[Wiktionary lists "narcist"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/narcist) as an "alternative form of narcissist." A few other online dictionaries list it as well, but none have much information on it.

It doesn't say nonstandard, so does that imply it's an accepted spelling by the bodies that be? Is it just rarely used? Archaic?

The only etymological information I could find was at Wiktionary:

> First attested in the 20th century. Probably a borrowing, compare
> English *narcist* and German *Narzisst*. Ultimately from Latin
> *Narcissus*, from Ancient Greek Νάρκισσος (*Nárkissos*). *This etymology is incomplete. You can help Wiktionary by elaborating on the
> origins of this term.*

Do you know more about the etymology of "narcist" and whether this is an accepted spelling? Perhaps an academic with access to more in-depth materials can provide further information.

Comment: What do other dictionaries say?

Comment: Which do most people go with [[Google 1-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=narcist%2Cnarcissist&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnarcist%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnarcissist%3B%2Cc0)]? Do these findings make one the 'preferred version'? Is there any good reason to buck the trend here?

Comment: The full (subscription only) [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/noresults?browseType=sortAlpha&noresults=true&page=1&pageSize=20&q=narcist&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch) is still more or less the "definitive" guide to valid usages. And they say **No dictionary entries found for ‘narcist’.**

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That does not matter. I'm caring about being technically correct. I use obscure and archaic words all the time, and old meanings for words all the time. I just care that it's an accepted spelling, or in other words not nonstandard which means it's used colloquially, but proper English speakers don't recognize it. Looks like it's a result of an alternative spelling that came from the Latin or Germanic roots.

Personally, I use Wiktionary as it's better maintained and generally has all of the definitions.

Comment: While there is a lot good in Wiktionary, it is not particularly trustworthy. Anybody can write anything there (and they often do), and they give -no- nuance (like frequency of use, if it is standard, etc).

Comment: 'Narcist' is an acceptable alternative for 'narcissist' much less than 'probly' is an acceptable alternative for 'probably'. People may write it but it's incorrect by the most charitable meaning of incorrect.

Comment: @Mitch Yes, 'grammatical' and 'acceptable' are far from exact synonyms. According to Orwell, the outlandish is unacceptable. And there are few better qualified than he. Him. He was.

Comment: It's the correct spelling in Dutch, a language close to English. Perhaps the author of the Wiktionary article was confused?

Comment: I don't get why this question was closed. There are lots of acceptable words that are not in dictionaries. It may be obvious to most people that 'narcist' is not acceptable spelling in English (but might be a reasonable attempt at spelling if you've never seen it before and just heard another person pronounce it). So it is a reasonable question to need an answer.

Comment: It's a word, although I would not advocate its use. I can provide research if someone can reopen the question.

Comment: As the question itself makes clear, the name from which the word is derived is Narc**iss**us. Why isn't that enough to settle the matter?

Comment: @TinfoilHat I believe the question is open now. The research might actually update Wiktionary to provide more information. I think it might be one of those words where an English professor would correct you, and you might actually have an argument for the usage. I'd only use it for stylized purposes.

Comment: @Mitch A narcist is somebody who makes a habit of narcing on their neighbors. :->

Comment: @tchrist ...while picnicing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if your professor or even your mom says *narcist* is unacceptable, it’s unacceptable. You will get no points trying to make a case for a word that floats in clouds of obscurity headed for oblivion.

Yes, *narcist* is a word—one Wiktionary categorizes as “dated”:

> Formerly in common use, and still in occasional use, but now
> unfashionable;... *Dated* is not as strong as *archaic* or
> *obsolete*.
>  <sub>Source: [Wiktionary Appendix:Glossary: **dated**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#dated)</sub>

Under “quotations,” [Wiktionary cites a few sources using the word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/narcist).

If you don’t believe in Wiktionary, here’s *narcist* in *Webster’s New International Dictionary of the English Language* (Second Edition, Unabridged, 1939):

> **nar´cism**, *n.*   Narcissism. **— nar´cist**, *n.* **— nar·cis´tic**, *adj.*

[image: narcism entry]

*Oxford English Dictionary* does not list *narcist*, but it does list *narcism*. In the second edition of the OED (1989), *narcism* makes an appearance under the entry for *narcissism*, along with the labels *erroneous* and *incorrect*:

> **narcissism,** *n.*
>  Self-love and admiration that find emotional satisfaction in self-contemplation; occas. (erron.) **narcism**.
> <sub>1938   H. A. MURRAY *Explor. in Personality* iii. 180  
> Narcism (or Egophilia) is technical for self-love.</sub>
>  <sub>1970
>   HINSIE & CAMPBELL
> *Psychiatric Dict.* (ed. 4) 487/2   *Narcism*, a shortened (and incorrect) form of narcissism.</sub>
>  <sub>Source: [Oxford English
> Dictionary](https://oed.com), Second Edition (1989) (login
> required)</sub>

However, in the OED’s third and most recent edition (2003), *narcism* appears as its own entry, without reference to erroneousness or incorrectness. Here we see that *narcism* was “formed within English, by clipping or shortening”:

> **narcism,** *n.*
> **Frequency (in current use):**  [Band 2<sup>*</sup>]
>  <sub>[*Band 2 contains words which occur fewer than 0.01 times per million words
> in typical modern English usage. These are almost exclusively terms
> which are not part of normal discourse and would be unknown to most
> people. Many are technical terms from specialized discourses....
> ]</sub>
> **Origin:** Formed within English, by clipping or shortening; perhaps modelled on a German lexical item, or perhaps modelled on a French
> lexical item. **Etymon:** NARCISSISM *n.*
> **Etymology:** Shortened < NARCISSISM *n.*, after German *Narzissmus* (1924 in Freud) or French *narcisme* (1918).
>
> *Chiefly Psychology.*
>
> = NARCISSISM *n.*
>
> <sub>1938   H. A. MURRAY *Explor. in Personality* iii. 180  
> Narcism (or Egophilia) is technical for self-love.</sub>
>  <sub>1945
>   *Mod. Lang. Notes* **60** 198   These birds [in Rilke’s
> *Flamingos*] are not supposed to seduce *each other* (which would be only a natural biological fact) but themselves in their extreme
> complacent narcism.</sub>
>  <sub>1951   J. S. BRUNER in R. R.
> Blake & G. V. Ramsey *Perception* v. 142   The theory of
> schizophrenia as a regression to primary narcism, a withdrawal from
> object relationships.</sub>
>  <sub>1999   *Calgary* (Alberta)
> *Herald* (Nexis) 7 Aug. g9   They may be getting increasingly selfish and self-absorbed because of the narcism increasing, so they
> tell their spouse that he or she is selfish.</sub>
>  <sub>Source:
> [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com), Third Edition (2003)
> (login required)</sub>

Noted under the entry *narcissism* in *Sigmund Freud, His Personality, His Teaching, & His School* by Fritz Wittels (1924) is:

> [Some Freudian writers shorten the term to
> “narcism.”](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sigmund_Freud_His_Personality_His_Teachi/jPB9AAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22narcism%22)

[image: narcissism entry]

Indeed, in [*A General Introduction to Psychoanalysis*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/38219/38219-h/38219-h.htm) by
Sigmund Freud (translated by [G. Stanley Hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G._Stanley_Hall) and published in 1920), *narcistic* appears 34 times and *narcism* 21. These have been shortened from the German versions  *narzißtische/n* (*narcissitic*) and *narzißmus* (*narcissism*) respectively (see [*Vorlesungen zur Einführung in die Psychoanalyse*](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/freud/vorles1/chap026.html)).

Nowadays, there are few, if any, acceptable reasons to use the word *narcist*. In doing so, you would surely issue an invitation to doubt your ability to spell, and the issuance of such an invitation alone shows an error in judgement.

Comment: Alright, it sounds like it might be growing in popularity slowly. So, it's like "cromulent" where you just need to use it till it becomes an accepted word.

Comment: @ZeroPhase I think you took the wrong lesson from Tinfoil's answer. Note the closing "Nowadays, there are few, if any, acceptable reasons to use the word narcist. In doing so, you would surely issue an invitation to doubt your ability to spell, and the issuance of such an invitation alone shows an error in judgement."

Answer (score 4):

If [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=narcist%2Cnarcissist&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) tells you it's outranked by a factor 2000, you can be sure it's not a widely accepted spelling.

[image]

When you look at the [top hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22narcist%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2005,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en), you can see that the first one is even taken from a [Dutch magazine](https://books.google.nl/books?id=WMdyzwu02QMC&pg=PA351&dq=%22narcist%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2gbbK8f3tAhXrIMUKHU61BYgQ6AEwAHoECAUQAg) mistakenly included in the English corpus.

For the record, in Dutch we *do* use the word 'narcist', and 'narcissist' is wrong. The [etymology section you cited](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/narcist#Etymology) is also for the *Dutch* usage of the word, not for the English. As for *why* we shortened the word, I don't have a clue.

Comment: Is that how it works? What if there's some etymology that supports it as valid?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. Language doesn't always follow logical rules.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is. Though not widely used. [1](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/narcist)

The more popular spelling is: Narcissist

> a person who is overly self-involved, and often vain and selfish. [2](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/narcist)

> a person who suffers from narcissism, deriving erotic gratification from admiration of their own physical or mental attributes. [2](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/narcist)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117929/discussion-on-answer-by-beulah-akindele-is-narcist-an-accepted-spelling-of-narci).